# How to pass hidden variable between function calls in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My problem is that I have to pass a `trace_id` between different functions.

So if `funA calls funB, funB calls funC and funC calls funD`, then I generate a trace_id at `funA` and access it at `funD`. This trace_id has to be stack local.

However I don't want to pass it as an argument but as a hidden variable. The reason being that `funA and funD` are part of my framework while the user of the framework writes `funB and funC.`

I can inspect the current frame but the problem is that funA is decorated and the decorator generates this trace_id. So using

```
trace_id = frame[0].f_locals.get('x_trace_id', None)
```

doesn't work.

What can I do now?

Comment: Sounds like the job for a class.

Comment: Your explanation isn't really an explanation - what is a *"hidden variable"*, and why does B and C being written by someone else necessitate it?

Comment: Use a global variable

Comment: @Rolf I can't use a global variable because funA is called in an async environment.

Comment: In that case, if all else fails, write it into a config file

Answer (score 1):

In Python it is simple for both funA and funD to have access to a shared global namespace via the import statement.  If they both import a module, names in that module become shared.  So that enables you to share data between them without modifying the intervening calls.

You mention that the variable you want to share should be, in some sense, stack or thread-local.  To get that working you can make the shared object in the "global" module a dictionary keyed by an identifier, e.g. the thread id.  In this case `frame[0]` would be a possibility.

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks.